# Call anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, typeerror

I know this could be similiar with someone, but i'm sure, i'm not yet found the answer here, i just want to call an anonymous function in a variable, which like this

```
me.req.ref['index']['index'] = function() {
    var a, mount;
        return {
            function: function(fout) {
                mount = new loading(fout, "flogin");
                mount.start("Login granted, redirecting..");

                a = setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = purl+"profile";
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

and i want to call it like this.

```
var ret;

ret = new me.req.ref[refcode][resp];
ret.function(fout);
```

but it show an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: ret is not a function

i implement this in method `loading()` and work well, here the code.

```
function loading(e, code) {
    var x = 0;
    return {
        start: function(str) {
            var dot, y;

            dot = [".","..","...","...."];
            y = 0;

            e.style.height = "auto";
            e.style.maxHeight = "100%";

            e.innerHTML = str+dot[y]+" ("+x+")";
            me.time.mount[code] = setInterval(function() {
                e.innerHTML = str+dot[y]+" ("+x+")";
                x++; y++;

                if(y>3) {
                    y = 0;
                }
            }, 1000);
        },
        stop: function() {
            clearInterval(me.time.mount[code]);
        }
    }
}
```

the way that i call `loading()` is like this.

```
mount = new loading(fout, me.time.code["flogin"]);
mount.start("string"); // if i want to start an loading.
mount.stop(); // if i want to shutdown the loading.
```

any solution? please help.
thanks for any correction.

Comment: Are you sure this is the error you are getting? You are calling `ret` nowhere in the shown code. Also, should you do so, it would be obvious, as `ret` is supposed to be an object, right?

Comment: There's technically nothing wrong with the way you are calling the function, it should work so long as the `ret` object actually has the key `function` on it which is bound to a function. When you debug it, is the `ret` object defined? is `ret.function` defined? In your first code block, you are binding to `me.req.ref['index']['index']`, when you call it are `refcode` and `resp` equal to `'index'`?

Comment: @ASDFGerta correct, but when i call it is said `not a function`.

Comment: @SimonK the code block is already consecutive. Sure, the `refcode` and `resp` is the `'index'`.

Comment: But `ret` is not supposed to be a function, from your code, `ret` should be an object, with a property called "function", which is a function. That's why you do `ret.function(fout);` - i don't understand.

Comment: so you mean it could be different if i call it like this `ret().function(fout)`

Comment: No, what i mean is that the code you show does not include any call of `ret`, and therefore the error does not make any sense, given what is provided. Should you however call `ret` somwhere in code that is not shown, the error is to be expected, as `ret` is not a function, as described above.

Comment: it was my mistake, i'm not correcting it well, thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the problem in here is calling the method like this `ret().function(fout)`, when the `ret` is an `Object`, so this problem answered, to call the function i need to write it like this `ret.function(fout)`.